# Why might the functional form of a distribution be "inappropriate" for a particular application?

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, nonparametric, pattern-recognition, density-estimation

Working through Bishop's Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning(a great read so far!) and on page 67 he says:

> "One limitation of the parametric approach is that it assumes a specific functional form for the distribution which may turn out to be inappropriate for a particular application"

Why might it be that the functional form of a distribution is inappropriate for a particular application?
An illustrative example would also be much appreciated.

Comment: fantastic mr fox --> stochastic mr fox? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not functional forms themselves are inappropriate, but the assumption part.
It's a rigid approach (the parameters are often allowed to vary, but it's quite restrictive compared to other approaches).

While we have functional forms for a lot of things, many other distributions are not even expressible by (our human) functions.

If you need to assume a distribution, what happens when it's misspecified or inconsistent?

So that's the fact that Bishop is alluding to.
Non-parametric or semi-parametric approaches try to bypass that.